# Decorators in NestJS not working correctly when validating inner DTO in query parameters

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I'm learning to develop an API using Nest, TypeOrm, and Postgres.

One task involves retrieving data from query parameters.

To accomplish this, I'm using a validation pipe in main.ts:

```
app.useGlobalPipes(
  new ValidationPipe({
    whitelist: true,
    forbidNonWhitelisted: true,
    transform: true,
    transformOptions: {
      enableImplicitConversion: true,
    },
  }),
);
```

My controller looks like this:

```
@Get()
findAll(@Query() params?: OuterFilterDto<InnerFilterDto>) {
  console.log(params);
}
```

My `OuterFilterDto` is a simple DTO that has one property of generic type F for `InnerFilterDto` and other DTOs:

```
@Transform(({ value }) => JSON.parse(value), { toClassOnly: true })
@IsOptional()
filter?: F;
```

The `InnerFilterDto` has the following property:

```
@IsString()
@MinLength(2)
@MaxLength(25)
name?: string;
```

I need to send a GET request to an endpoint like .../example?filter=%7B%22name8%22%3A%22Joe%22%7D.

I'm using "name8" instead of "name" to see if I get an error, but it doesn't happen. The decorators don't work as expected.

All the solutions I've tried, such as manual validation, haven't worked.

I would appreciate it if someone could help me with this issue.